# After flagging as duplicate, can I see how many others have done so?

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions

Normally, if I flag as duplicate, I can see if anyone else has done so by a number in the corner, like this:

[image]

Currently though, after I've flagged I can no longer see how many people have also flagged because:

[image]

After I've flagged, can I see if anyone else has flagged besides me?

Comment: For starters, you get this when you receive the privilege to cast full votes; you can see how many others have voted to close (or reopen) a question.  But...why do you want to see this?  What value would you receive from it?

Comment: When the first user flags as a duplicate, a "Possible duplicate of X" comment is automatically created, and when other users flag as a duplicate of that same question, that comment is automatically upvoted. So you can get an idea of how many users have flagged as a duplicate by seeing how many upvotes the possible duplicate comment has.

Comment: What is the point of _flagging_ something as a duplicate when it already has an active duplicate flag on it? Multiple close flags don't do anything more than a single close flag does.

Comment: But the main page shows "close (4)" for instance after you voted. So it means that 3 people voted to close. Even if you dont know the type of closure anymore for each previous closure (last closure reason wins when question is eventually closed)

Comment: @Tiny Arguably, one should not adjust their behavior around implementation details. :-) It is reasonable to assume that the system would prioritize questions with multiple closure flags over those with only one for the purposes of sorting in the review queues, and in case that starts happening in the future, I'm not sure we should go around telling everyone to make assumptions about how it works now.